# column-count css and column separation

Tags: html, css

I have such url:  http://xn----7sbabhi8cwaajmue5o.xn--p1ai/cars/search/by_man_and_model?by_manufacturer=115

there you could see that i have three columns

i have such troulbe: id="manufacturers-list" if i delete min, and height, i see that my li is separated in different colums
[image]

[image]
, but how to prevent this?

i didn't get why i get this separation(( why it slice my li?

css:

```
width: 690px;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that's separating your content into different columns is the CSS `column-count` property (including the vendor prefixes.)

To explain both your images, the first looks like you have a set height with `overflow: hidden` which is going to conceal every single list item that flows past that height. If you have 50 list items but your container only has height enough for five, you're not going to see more than five.

The second looks like you've removed your height and given a `column` property.

I just looked at the site and you might want to remove the `display: inline-block` style from `.man-area`, remove `overflow-hidden` from the outside container (`#vip-offers`)

And SOMEWHERE you have inline javascript (or styles) giving that parent container a fixed height. I would definitely not recommend giving a fixed height with a hidden overflow. It just doesn't bode well unless you're trying to achieve a specific effect.